# Prove that point is uniquely defined by the distances from 3 points

Tags: geometry

Let A, B, C be distinct points. Then any point P in the plane is uniquely
determined by the three distances P A, P B, P C; that is, if P, Q are points in the plane with
P A = QA, P B = QB, P C = QC, then P = Q.

How do I go about proving this? I have tried using triangles and trying to prove that A, B and C must be collinear for this statement to be wrong (P is not equal to Q). Could anyone direct me?

Comment: A point is NOT determined by its distances from TWO distinct points, but its possible locations are quite limited. Show that the distance to a third (non-collinear) point reduces the possibilities to just one. (Or, show that the distance to a third point *doesn't* help, then that third point must be collinear with the first two.) ... Incidentally, since non-collinearity is necessary for uniqueness, you should mention it in the statement of the property.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have stated this it is incorrect (as you suggest) because you can have $P\neq Q$ if $A, B, C$ are co-linear. If we make the additional assumption that $A, B, C$ are no co-linear then it is true.

To see this note let $\mathcal{C}_A$ be the circle with center $A$ and radius the distance from $P$ to $A$, $d(P,A)$. Then $P$ and $Q$ both lie on $\mathcal{C}_A$. Similarly, both $P$ and $Q$ lie on $\mathcal{C}_B$ the circle with center $B$ and radius $d(P,B)$. Since $A\neq B$ then $\mathcal{C}_A\neq\mathcal{C}_B$.

Now note that two distinct circles can meet in at most 2 points. Since $P\in\mathcal{C}_A\cap\mathcal{C}_B$ then there are two cases.

Case 1: $P=\mathcal{C}_A\cap\mathcal{C}_B$, then by the above logic we also have $Q\in\mathcal{C}_A\cap\mathcal{C}_B$, thus $P=Q$.

Case 2: There is a point $R$ such that $\{R,P\}=\mathcal{C}_A\cap\mathcal{C}_B$ with $P\neq R$. By above we have that $Q\in\mathcal{C}_A\cap\mathcal{C}_B$ so we just need to show that $Q\neq R$.

Since $A, B, C$ are no co-linear then $C$ does not lie on the line through $A$ and $B$. From here you assume that $Q=R$ and use some elementary geometry (eg. drop a perpendicular from $C$ to the line $\overline{AB}$ and call the intersectoin $O$) and use some trig for $\triangle COP$ and $\triangle COQ$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the basic principle how GPS works. Try to write the matrix and use the uniqueness of reduced row echelon form

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $P$ and $Q$ both exist and are two points that lie distance $a$ from $A$, distance $b$ from $B$ and distance $c$ from $C$, where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all distinct points.

Draw a circle of radius $a$ centered at $A$ and a circle of radius $b$ centered at $B$.  Because these are non-concentric circles, they have $0$, $1$, or $2$ points of intersection. If there were zero points of intersection, $P$ and $Q$ wouldn't exist.  If there is one point of intersection, that point is both $P$ and $Q$.  If there are two points of intersection, then either $P$ and $Q$ are both the same point or the two points are $P$ and $Q$ in some order.

If the two points are $P$ and $Q$ in some order, then point $C$ being equidistant from both must be located on the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PQ}$.  However, as $A$ and $B$ are on that perpendicular bisector as well, that would make $A$, $B$, and $C$ colinear.

Therefore, either $P$ and $Q$ are the same point or $A$, $B$, and $C$ are colinear

Comment: Thanks, the first few paragraphs helped me get the idea right. Thanks again!